# In-App purchase subscription cancellation issue

Tags: objective-c, swift, in-app-purchase, skpaymenttransaction

I implemented in-App purchase in iOS app (let's take one month subscription), it's working perfectly. 
I want to ask if user cancel the subscription (before the end date) from iTunes then iTunes sends something to device or not? so we can locally update our app according to subscription.
I knows iTunes sends notification to server but my main concern on device, so we can update our app without server api calls.

Comment: check for subscription at login/app opening  time through api call, it is good practice.

Comment: Thanks, but i want to know there is only device side implementation possible or not(not server api call). Does iTunes provides some response to device that subscription cancelled?